# How to cut polygons in ArcMap using manually entered coordinates?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, coordinates

I would like to cut polygons with a line determined by coordinates. I have the coordinates in a separate pdf file (for reasons beyond my control) and I would like to manually enter them during the cutting procedure.

I know, and I admit it is a bad practice, and I know I could extract the coordinates, load them to ArcMap and create a point feature and then snap to those points, but this is not what I want.

Is there maybe a tool that I haven't found yet? Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What does the PDF look like? If possible add a screenshot of the PDF and the polygon you are trying to split.